# oAuth suddenly throwing timestamp error

Tags: oauth, timestamp

I've an API which uses oAuth for authentication.
Everything has been working smoothly for months until last week, when I started noticing oAuth was throwing `400` errors due to a `Expired timestamp, yours X, ours Y`.

I'm guessing that some changes on server (it's a shared hosting machine) reset or messed something with the local time.

I can't figure out any other reason, but I'd like to know if there's any other debuggin' technique that may help me.

PS: Using PHP 5.2 and the oAuth 1.0a php implementation

Answer (score 0):

The OAuth server should always use UTC time as the basis for checking timestamps. Assuming that you send the correct timestamp based on UTC, check the 'ours' timestamp has the correct time in UTC. If not then its most likely there is a problem with the server time or the OAuth timestamp calculation on the server.